# Account screen(swiping from the left or by ||| button) like in play store

Tags: android

I'm sorry if i sound stupid, but I don't know how this feature called, so i don't have any idea what to look for.

The feature is: In some apps like "play store" or "solid explorer" we have this screen that opens when we swipe from left corner.
I want to build one for my application so it would be a user's personal space when he would be able to find log out button, settings and other info.

Do anyone know in which direction i should look?

[image: Play Store Preview]

Comment: feature is called as navigational drawer in android and here is the link to download its code and tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: if your working in android studio i know there is a new project option that implements a nav drawer for you, I would suggest working from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these links for Navigation Drawer:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

http://javatechig.com/android/navigation-drawer-android-example

Answer (score 2):

Its called Navigation Menu. Follow the link

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html